How to maintain session between django and react between multiple requests?
I am trying set a variable vendor_data in my views to the request.session in django.
class MyClass(APIview):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        request.session['vendor_data'] = vendor_data # this is a dict 

Then I am trying to access this vendor_data key in another DRF view, like this:
class AnotherClass(APIview):
    def post(self, request, format=None): 
        vendor_data = request.session['vendor_data']

But I get keyError, missing key "vendor_data".
More Context:
The APIs are running on an EC2 with the port open.
The APIs are being requested from a localhost react environment, from a PC.
My django settings.py allows all host and
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3002',   # react app port
    'http://127.0.0.1:3002',
    'http://10.0.90.2:8008',   # dummy django app port
    'http://127.0.0.1:8008', 
    'http://localhost:8008', 
] 

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 300
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'


I am trying to register and autheticate a user via OTP. I am storing the user details in session until they verify the OTP.
But I cannot verify the OTP because, of the keyerror I am receiving in the other view.
EDIT:
Here is the react code
try {
      console.log("Submitting OTP:", otp);
     
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://IP:8008/api/otp-verification/",
        { otp: String(otp) },  // Make sure OTP is passed as a string
        {
         
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
         
            // Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,  // Uncomment if using the token
          },
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      );
 
      console.log("Response:", response);
 
      if (response.status === 200) {
        alert("OTP verified successfully!");
        localStorage.removeItem('otp');  // Optionally remove OTP from localStorage
        navigate("/Login");  // Redirect to login page after successful OTP verification
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("OTP verification failed:", error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
     
      // Handle specific error messages based on the response
      if (error.response && error.response.data) {
        setErrorMessage(error.response.data.message || "Invalid OTP. Please try again.");
      } else {
        setErrorMessage("An error occurred. Please try again later.");
      }
    } finally {
      // Hide the loading state after the request is finished
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };


Please show the react code you use for authentication

@LordElrond added the react code in the question, please see.
